# Tensorflow lite model not working on android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, tflite

I have a tflite model in unity that takes input image and predicts its output. However, when I exported it as apk, the model is not working as I am not getting the predicted class in output screen. Does anyone know how to run it actually. Do I need to have any android foreground services or do I need to add any extra script for android build.

I have not given any extra script for android. Is it necessary? My model works perfectly in unity but not in android device (only prediction is not working)

Comment: You have to check whether it is compressed when it is packed in .apk . Check this
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support#import_gradle_dependency_and_other_settings